# Connecting to X2goserver from Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x2go

I've installed X2goserver on an Ubuntu machine. I can see that it's running as so:

```
systemctl status x2goserver.service
● x2goserver.service - X2Go Server Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/x2goserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-09-19 10:53:30 NZST; 39min ago
```

However, I can't connect to it from Windows (via X2Go Client), the connection attempt times out.

I understand that this connection should be over port 22 (TCP), but I can't telnet to this port on the server, and when I list the listening ports on the server, port 22 isn't in there.

How can I make X2GoServer listen on port 22? I've made sure to unblock it on the firewall.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux usage questions should be posted to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: You're right, my bad. That said, this one is now solved thanks to Christian below and me remembering I changed the default SSH port a while back :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 22 is the ssh port. So without knowing x2go, I cannot imagine any other explanation than x2go using ssh -- which of course makes sense. If that's the issue, then make sure `openssh-server` is installed.

Comment: Ok. I've installed that. Now if I run this command...

systemctl list-units --type=service

...I get a list which includes these lines:

ssh.service                                           loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server
x2goserver.service                                    loaded active running X2Go Server Daemon   

However, I'm still unable to telnet to port 22. If I run this command...
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
...no line comes up w hich includes port 22.

I may have changed the SSH port a while back. Where would I check/configure this?

Comment: Disregard above, the problem was that I had changed my default SSH port a while back, changing it back to 22 (or I guess I could also change the port in the X2go client) has solved the problem. I'm marking your answer as correct because it let me down that path, but you may want to put an edit in your question, assuming this whole question doesn't get wiped for being on the wrong board.